# Does Apache POI API support PPTX2PNG conversion (in java programs) for pptx generated by LibreOffice Impress?

Tags: java, apache-poi, powerpoint

I am trying to convert the pptx to png images using apache-poi in java but it doesn't work with pptx generated by LibreOffice Impress (works fine with others ) and there is no exception thrown.

The resulting images I get are just the background with out the text content of the pptx.

Please see the links for the results.

[The resulting image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5tcS.png)

[Screen shot of Actual pptx slide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oweg7.png)

This is the basic code I got :

```
package com.preview;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XMLSlideShow;
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFSlide;

public class PptxToPng {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("~/Downloads/pptx/SamplePPTX.pptx");      

    XMLSlideShow ppt = new XMLSlideShow(is);
    is.close();
    double zoom = 2;
    AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
    at.setToScale(zoom, zoom);
    Dimension pgsize = ppt.getPageSize();
    List<XSLFSlide> slide = ppt.getSlides();

    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage((int)Math.ceil(pgsize.width*zoom),
            (int)Math.ceil(pgsize.height*zoom), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D graphics = img.createGraphics();

    graphics.setTransform(at);
    graphics.fill(new Rectangle2D.Float(0, 0, pgsize.width, pgsize.height));

    // Draw first page in the PPTX. First page starts at 0 position
    slide.get(0).draw(graphics);

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("~/Downloads/pptx/converted.png");  
    javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(img, "png", out);
    out.close();
    ppt.close();
    System.out.println("DONE");
}

}
```

Comment: Did you try with the most recent version of Apache POI (3.14 beta 1?)

Comment: No, I am using Apache POI 3.13. Let me try with the beta and I will let you know.

Comment: Still the same problem with  Apache POI (3.14 beta 1?)

Answer (score 0):

**poi-ooxml-3.15.jar** comes with a tool called **PPTX2PNG**. It can be found in the package **org.apache.poi.xslf.util**

Execute it eg with parameters `-scale 1 -format jpg pptx-file.pptx` and it should write an image file to the same directory as the origin pptx file.

*BTW: despite the name, it can write to png, jpg and gif formats.*